# Adding dashed line below element in matrix

Tags: rules

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{easybmat}
\title{Test}
\author{Bob}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

 $\left[\begin{BMAT}(@){c}{c.c.c}
X_1 \\ X_2 \\ X_3
\end{BMAT}\right]$
\end{document}
```

This adds a dashed line below X_1 and a dashed line below X_2. I only want a dashed line below X_2. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Change the format specification from

```
\begin{BMAT}(@){c}{c.c.c}
```

to

```
\begin{BMAT}(@){c}{cc.c}
```

An example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{easybmat}
\title{Test}
\author{Bob}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

 $\left[\begin{BMAT}(@){c}{cc.c}
X_1 \\ X_2 \\ X_3
\end{BMAT}\right]$
\end{document}
```

[image]